# generic Interface vb

Tags: vb.net, generics

Trying to get my head around generic interfaces and classes. How do I 'get T' when using my class in the new method and call data.method using this type?

```
Public MustInherit Class RepositoryBase(Of T)
    Implements IRepository(Of T)

    Private Data As IDAL

    Public Sub New()
        Data = DTOParserFactory.GetParser(T.GetType().ToString())
    End Sub

    Public Sub delete(BaseDTO As T) Implements Domain.Business.IRepository(Of T).delete
        'Data.delete(Convert.ChangeType(BaseDTO, TypeOf(Type))
    End Sub

    Public Function getAll() As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of T) Implements Domain.Business.IRepository(Of T).getAll
        'Return Data.getAll()()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Well, what do you mean by “get T”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you need to get the `Type` object for T?

In your constructor

```
Public Sub New()
    Data = DTOParserFactory.GetParser(GetType(T).ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: that works for the constructor, thanks. how do i call a function
Data.delete(BaseDTO)
basedto does not inherit from or implement constraint type. do i need to convert T to an object that implements this?

Comment: In a word: Yes. However it would be good to have these methods on the constraint type, otherwise why have the constraint type at all? I  assumed the `Delete` & `GetAll` methods were on the constraint type. That's why you would constrain this generic class by that type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super clear on the question, but perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Assuming you have a common base class `BaseDTO` then you would define your RepositoryBase class like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class RepositoryBase(Of T As BaseDTO)
```

Then you declare an instace of the class like this:

```
Dim userRepository As New RepositoryBase(Of User)()
```

What this does is constrain T to be a subclass of BaseDTO, and gives you access to all of BaseDTO's methods.